# Can not create a database in my computer. java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException error

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

I can not create a database in my computer.  When I tried changing the java.policy file, it denied my access.  I don't know what's going on.  But on netBeans I saw this error:

```
"An error occurred while creating your database:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
java.net.connectException: Error connecting to server localhost on
port 1527 with message. Connection refused. "
```

What's going on.  How can I fix this problem, and create a database with out my operating system denying my own access?

Comment: How are you trying to create a database - which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using java DB on netbeans

Comment: same error with me! :(